# How to encode multiple features at once with SciKit Learn transform

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn

I am trying to encode some categorical features to be able to use them as features in a machine learning model, at the moment I have the following code:

```
data_path = '/Users/novikov/Assignment2/epl-training.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()


data['HomeTeam'] = le.fit_transform(data.HomeTeam.values)
data['AwayTeam'] = le.fit_transform(data.AwayTeam.values)
data['FTR'] = le.fit_transform(data.FTR.values)
data['HTR'] = le.fit_transform(data.HTR.values)
data['Referee'] = le.fit_transform(data.Referee.values)
```

This works fine, however this is not ideal because if there were 100 features to encode, it would take way too long to do it by hand. How do I automate the process? I have tried implementing a loop:

```
label_encode = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTR', 'HTR', 'Referee']

for feature in label_encode:
    method = 'data.' + feature + '.values'
    data[feature] = le.fit_transform(method)
```

But I get `ValueError: bad input shape ()`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-1b8fb6164d2d> in <module>()
     11     method = 'data.' + feature + '.values'
     12     print(method)
---> 13     data[feature] = le.fit_transform(method)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    109         y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
    110         """
--> 111         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    112         self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    113         return y

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    612         return np.ravel(y)
    613 
--> 614     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    615 
    616 

ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

None of the variations of this code (like just putting `data.feature.values`) seem to work. There must be a way of doing it other than writing it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, `method = 'data.' + feature + '.values'` will not work - it is a string itself! Try instead

```
method = data[feature].values
```

or

```
for feature in label_encode:
    data[feature] = le.fit_transform(data[feature].values)
```

Answer (score 4):

The way the encoder object works is that when you `fit` it stores some meta data in the object's attributes.  These attributes get used when you want to transform the data.  `fit_transform` is a convenience method to `fit` and `transform` in one step.

When you decide to use the same object to do another `fit_transform`, you are overwriting the the stored meta data.  That is fine if you don't want to use the objects `inverse_transform`.

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'HomeTeam':[1, 3, 27],
    'AwayTeam':[9, 8, 100],
    'FTR':['dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
    'HTR': [*'XYY'],
    'Referee': [*'JJB']
})
```

---

#### Answer to your question

`update` and `apply`

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encode = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTR', 'HTR', 'Referee']

df.update(df[label_encode].apply(le.fit_transform))
df

   AwayTeam FTR HTR  HomeTeam Referee
0         1   1   0         0       1
1         0   0   1         1       1
2         2   1   1         2       0
```

---

#### How I'd Do It

Each separate encoder is captured in the `le` dictionary for potential later use

```
from collections import defaultdict
le = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)
label_encode = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTR', 'HTR', 'Referee']

df = df.assign(**{k: le[k].fit_transform(df[k]) for k in label_encode})
df

   AwayTeam FTR HTR  HomeTeam Referee
0         1   1   0         0       1
1         0   0   1         1       1
2         2   1   1         2       0
```

---

#### `pandas.factorize`

If you just want codes, you can use Pandas' `factorize`.  Note that this will not sort the final values and labels them in the order they first appear.

```
df.update(df[label_encode].apply(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]))
df

   AwayTeam FTR HTR  HomeTeam Referee
0         0   0   0         0       0
1         1   1   1         1       0
2         2   0   1         2       1
```

#### Numpy's `unique`

This does sort the final values and will look like `LabelEncoder`

```
df.update(df[label_encode].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)[1]))

   AwayTeam FTR HTR  HomeTeam Referee
0         1   1   0         0       1
1         0   0   1         1       1
2         2   1   1         2       0
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just fixing your code adding `pd.eval`

```
label_encode = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTR', 'HTR', 'Referee']

for feature in label_encode:
    method = 'data.' + feature + '.values'
    data[feature] = le.fit_transform(pd.eval(method))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little awkward but you access the values from the series and then call fit transform on that, while selecting the series inside the for loop "X[c]=" to indicate you want to assign values back to the DF.

```
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1, 3, 27],
    'B':[9, 8, 100],
    'C':['dog', 'cat', 'dog']})
print(X.head())

le = LabelEncoder()

for c in X.columns:

    X[c] = le.fit_transform(X[c].values)

X.head()
```