# Testing model gives error: "y contains previously unseen labels"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, label-encoding

```py
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from datetime import datetime
import joblib

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Data preprocessing
# Convert the "eligible_date" column to datetime
data['eligible_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['eligible_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Feature engineering
data['year'] = data['eligible_date'].dt.year
data['month'] = data['eligible_date'].dt.month
data['day'] = data['eligible_date'].dt.day
data['weekday'] = data['eligible_date'].dt.weekday

# Label encoding for the "country" and "package" columns
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['country_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['country'])
data['package_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['package'])
data['model_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['model'])

joblib.dump(label_encoder, 'label_encoder.pkl')

# Drop unnecessary columns
data.drop(['eligible_date', 'country', 'package','model'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Split the data into features and target
X = data.drop('payout', axis=1)
y = data['payout']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define an XGBoost model with hyperparameters
model = XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=1500,
    learning_rate=0.01,
    max_depth=3,
    subsample=0.8,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    objective='reg:squarederror',
    random_state=42
)

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(model, 'xgboost_model.pkl')

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the model
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

print("Mean Squared Error:", mse)
print("R-squared:", r2)

# You can also use cross-validation to assess model performance
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
cv_scores = -cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kf, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

print("Cross-Validation Mean Squared Error:", np.mean(cv_scores))

# Hyperparameter tuning using RandomizedSearchCV
param_dist = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 500, 1000, 1500],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 9],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
    'subsample': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=10, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kf, random_state=42)
random_search.fit(X, y)

print("Best Hyperparameters:", random_search.best_params_)

#### testing phase

loaded_label_encoder = joblib.load('label_encoder.pkl')
loaded_model = joblib.load('xgboost_model.pkl')

# Create a function to predict total payout for a given month
def predict_total_payout_for_month(target_time, model, encoder):
    # Create a sample DataFrame with one row for the specified month
    sampledata = pd.DataFrame({
        'eligible_date': pd.to_datetime([target_time], format='%Y-%m-%d'),
        #'eligible_date': [datetime.strptime(target_month, '%Y-%m')],
        'country': ['Malaysia'],  # Replace with a valid country name
        'package': ['Express 100K'],
        'model': ['Express'],# Replace with a valid package name
        'payout': [0]  # This value will be overwritten
    })
#data['eligible_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['eligible_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    # Data preprocessing
    # sampledata['month'] = sampledata['eligible_date'].dt.to_period('M')
    sampledata['year'] = sampledata['eligible_date'].dt.year
    sampledata['month'] = sampledata['eligible_date'].dt.month
    sampledata['day'] = sampledata['eligible_date'].dt.day
    sampledata['weekday'] = sampledata['eligible_date'].dt.weekday
    # Assuming "country" and "package" columns need encoding
    sampledata['country_encoded'] = encoder.fit_transform(sampledata['country'])
    sampledata['package_encoded'] = encoder.fit_transform(sampledata['package'])
    sampledata['model_encoded'] = encoder.fit_transform(sampledata['model'])
    print(sampledata)

    # Prepare the input features (X) for prediction
    X_new = sampledata[['year', 'month', 'day', 'weekday', 'country_encoded', 'package_encoded', 'model_encoded']]  # Make sure the columns match those used during training
    print(X_new)

    # Use the trained model to make predictions
    predicted_payout = model.predict(X_new)

    return predicted_payout  # Return the predicted payout for the specified month

# Specify the target month for prediction
target = '2023-11-15'  # Replace with the month you want to predict

# Use the function to make predictions
predicted_total_payout = predict_total_payout_for_month(target, loaded_model, loaded_label_encoder)

print(f"Predicted Total Payout for {target}: {predicted_total_payout}")
```

Running the test part the encoded values do not match. For example `malaysia` should be encoded as `79` but whatever country I put in the test, it encodes as `0`. I am loading the labeldata pickel to transform the test data.

How can I adjust it so that the labeling from training phase is applied to the testing phase?

Comment: You are fitting the encoder three consecutive times. At the end you'll keep only the third fit. Maybe you wanted to use `fit_transform` once and then just `transform`?

Comment: Yes that might be the issue, so i should fit_transform in one go to keep the label data. Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: is it possible to give me the adjusted parts? I'm having trouble fixing it

Comment: It seems you are trying to label-encode three different features. Are these target variables? Or features? From [scikit documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html): _This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X._ The reason, essentially, is that it makes your feature continuous. Use OHE instead. If you are sure about using label encoder, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484826/15032126.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are fitting a new LabelEncoder to the test data. To apply the same encoding as in the training phase to the testing data, you should use the `transform` method of the LabelEncoder you used during training.

```
def predict_total_payout_for_month(target_time, model, encoder):
    # some code ...
    sampledata['country_encoded'] = encoder.transform(sampledata['country'])
    sampledata['package_encoded'] = encoder.transform(sampledata['package'])
    sampledata['model_encoded'] = encoder.transform(sampledata['model'])
    # some code
```